# Showing vectors on plane

Tags: plotting

```
a = ParametricPlot3D[{1/4 (2 - 2 u - Sqrt[6] v), 1/4 (2 Sqrt[3] - 2 Sqrt[3] u + Sqrt[2] v), π/3 + v/Sqrt[2]},
      {u,0, 6 Pi}, {v, 0, 6 Pi},
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> False]

γ[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], t}

tg[t_] = D[γ[t], t]/ Simplify[Sqrt[D[γ[t], t].D[γ[t],t]]]

norm[t_] = D[tg[t], t]/Simplify[Sqrt[D[tg[t], t].D[tg[t], t]]]

binorm[t_] = Cross[norm[t], tg[t]]

b = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{γ[Pi/3], γ[Pi/3] + tg[Pi/3]}]}]

c = Graphics3D[{Blue, Arrow[{γ[Pi/3], γ[Pi/3] + norm[Pi/3]}]}]

d = Graphics3D[{Green, Arrow[{γ[Pi/3], γ[Pi/3] + binorm[Pi/3]}]}]

Show[a,b,c,d]
```

[image]

How do I get my vectors to look longer and somewhere in the middle of the plane?

Answer (score 5):

```
Show[a, b, c, d, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]